# TCP Server-Client large json

Tags: java, android, json, tcp

I currently have a TCP server (java desktop application) and client (android application) connected.

I can send json string from client to server and from server to client, my issue is sometimes i need to send from the server a large string which gets cut.

This is my code:

SERVER SIDE

```
public void sendResponse(String response){
  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(BufferedWriter(
                       new OutputStreamWriter(mClientSocket.getOutputStream())), true);

  if(writer != null && !writer.checkError()){
     writer.println(response);
     writer.flush();
  }
}
```

CLIENT SIDE

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream()));
String response;
while((response = input.readLine()) != null && mRun){
    Data data = new Gson().fromJson(response, Data.class);
    //when i try to convert the response to Data object using Gson
    //it gives me a com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at line 1 column 106498

}
```

as you can see the error on client side happens because the string was to large so it got cut off, 
can someone please tell me what to do in this case?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use a [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) instead of trying to read lines. Something like,

```
public void sendResponse(String response) {
    OutputStream os = mClientSocket.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
    dos.writeUTF(response);
    dos.flush();
}
```

Then, on the client

```
InputStream is = mSocket.getInputStream();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
String response = dis.readUTF(); // <-- not just one line. the entire string.
Data data = new Gson().fromJson(response, Data.class);
```

And, if it's a *really* large JSON response you might consider adding a [`GZIPInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) and [`GZIPOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html).

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(is));
```

and

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(os));
```

**Edit**

```
public void sendResponse(String response) {
    OutputStream os = mClientSocket.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(os));
    byte[] buff = response.getBytes("UTF-8");
    dos.writeInt(buff.length);
    dos.write(buff);
    dos.flush();
}
```

And then to read,

```
InputStream is = mSocket.getInputStream();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(is));
int len = dis.readInt();
byte[] buff = new byte[len];
dis.readFully(buff);
String response = new String(buff, "UTF-8");
Data data = new Gson().fromJson(response, Data.class);
```

Comment: Thanks Elliot, I tried both ways and it gave me java.io.UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long: 331533 bytes on server side

Comment: @anonimoo90 Then you'll need to split the `String` into a pieces, or send it as a `byte[]`.

Comment: how should i split it into pieces? and how to receive it ?

Comment: i am able to send the data from the server this time. but on client side when i retrieve it i get an IOException Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid block type

Comment: @anonimoo90 If you use the GZIPInputStream on the client you must use GZIPOutputStream on the server.

Comment: I use both GZIPInputStream on client and GZIPOuputStream on server and still same issue

Comment: @anonimoo90 Does it work if you remove the GZIP streams? You might have to close() the stream for it to finish. I'm not certain.

Comment: i removed the gzip and was able to send the json from server to client. On client the first attempt worked, the second attempt it said  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on byte[] buff = new byte[len];

Comment: @anonimoo90 I think you'll need to refactor your code. OutOfMemory? How much memory do you have?

Comment: It says E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 2097152167-byte allocation. ... my json is a jsonArray of information of two images (name, path, type, byte[] of image) one image is 76kb and the other one is 14kb which i converted from image file to byte[] and added to json